# Multiple databases are working in dev environment, but not test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, padrino

This is a Padrino project.  For some reason I am getting my second database loaded in the development environment, but not the test environment.  This is probably very specific to my project, and it's unlikely anyone can help... but I'm really stuck!  :)

mongoid.yml

```
defaults: &defaults
  host: localhost
  port: 27017
  max_retries_on_connection_failure: 2
  databases:
    seeds:
      database: seeds_db
      host: localhost
      port: 27018

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: db_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: db_test
```

loaded with:

```
Mongoid.load!(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/mongoid.yml')
```

My rspec_helper:

```
PADRINO_ENV = 'test' unless defined?(PADRINO_ENV)
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/boot.rb"
RSpec.configure do |conf|
  conf.include Rack::Test::Methods
end
```

My boot.rb:

```
PADRINO_ENV  = ENV["PADRINO_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= "development"  unless defined?(PADRINO_ENV)

PADRINO_ROOT = File.expand_path('../..', __FILE__) unless defined?(PADRINO_ROOT)

require 'rubygems' unless defined?(Gem)
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
Bundler.require(PADRINO_ENV, :default) 

require 'redis' unless defined?(Redis)
require 'padrino' unless defined?(Padrino)
require 'mongoid' unless defined?(Mongoid)

Dir.glob(File.join(PADRINO_ROOT, 'config/initializers', "*.rb")){ |file| require file}
Dir.glob(File.join(PADRINO_ROOT, 'config/constants', "*.rb")){ |file| require file}

Padrino.before_load do
end

Padrino.after_load do
    Card.load!
    Position.load!
end

Padrino.load!
```

But this is not working after I ported my project to Padrino.  I can't find anything in the documentation that explains why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trouble that Rspec use ENV["RACK_ENV"], instead PADRINO_ENV.
So in the boot.rb add line to define RACK_ENV to PADRINO_ENV:

```
PADRINO_ENV = ENV["PADRINO_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"] ||= "development"  unless defined?(PADRINO_ENV)
ENV["RACK_ENV"] = PADRINO_ENV
```

Answer (score 0):

I found someone loading their mongoid.yml this way on github, and this seems to work:

```
config_file = Padrino.root("config", "mongoid.yml")
if File.exists?(config_file)
  settings = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(config_file)).result)[Padrino.env.to_s]
  ::Mongoid.from_hash(settings) if settings.present?
end
```

Comment: Can you remember where you found this? I am having the same problem but I'm using Sinatra.